# What is a robust way to determine if two polygons overlap? Possible bug in RegionIntersection or Area

Tags: computational-geometry, regions, polygons

When trying to determine if two polygon objects overlap, I think the intuitive way to do this would be to use the `RegionIntersection` function to find the overlapping region, and `Area` to find the area of the overlap.

This works with two separated polygons,

```
{p1, p2} = {Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
   Polygon[1 + {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}}]};
Graphics[{Red, p1, Blue, p2}]
RegionIntersection[p1, p2]
Area@%
```

[image]

```
(* EmptyRegion[2] *)
(* 0 *)
```

as well as for two polygons that share an edge,

```
{p1, p2} = {Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
   Polygon[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}}]};
Graphics[{Red, p1, Blue, p2}]
RegionIntersection[p1, p2]
Area@%
```

[image]

```
(* Line[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}] *)
(* 0 *)
```

However, it doesn't work on these two simple triangles that clearly share an edge,

```
{p1, p2} = {Polygon[{{0., 0.354}, {-0.354, 0.}, {-0.707, 0.707}}], 
   Polygon[{{-0.707, -0.707}, {-0.354, 0.}, {-0.707, 0.707}}]};
Graphics[{Red, p1, Blue, p2}]
RegionIntersection[p1, p2]
Area@%

(* Polygon[{{-0.707, 0.707}, {-0.707, 0.707}, {-0.707, 0.707}}] *)
```

> During evaluation of In[86]:= Area::nmet: Unable to compute the area
>   of region Polygon[{{-0.707,0.707},{-0.707,0.707},{-0.707,0.707}}]. >>

```
(* Area[
 Polygon[{{-0.707, 0.707}, {-0.707, 0.707}, {-0.707, 0.707}}]] *)
```

First off, this is clearly the wrong answer for the intersection, as the polygons share the line segment `{-0.354, 0.}, {-0.707, 0.707}`, so the intersection should be a `Line`.

One workaround is to apply `Rationalize` to the `Polygons` before finding the intersection,

```
RegionIntersection[Rationalize@p1, Rationalize@p2]
Area@%
(* Line[{{-(707/1000), 707/1000}, {-(177/500), 0}}] *)
(* 0 *)
```

Another workaround is to reverse the coordinates for the second triangle,

```
RegionIntersection[p1, MapAt[Reverse, p2, {1}]]
Area@%
(* Line[{{-0.707, 0.707}, {-0.354, 0}}] *)
(* 0 *)
```

But I'm looking for a fool-proof, preferably fast way to do this.

So I ask you, is this a bug?  And if so, what is the best way to determine if two polygons overlap?

I have this, hackish, method right now, but it is much slower than `RegionIntersection`, which is already pretty slow when there are hundreds of polygons to consider.

```
intersectQ[p1_, p2_] := 
 Chop[Area[RegionUnion[p1, p2]] - Total[Area /@ {p1, p2}]] =!= 0
intersectQ[p1, p2]
(* False *)
```

### Edit

Here is another odd example of `RegionIntersection` bugging out in a related, but different, way.  Here we have two triangles that intersect at a single point,

```
{p1, p2} = {Polygon[{{0.322, 0.363}, {0.116, 0.472}, {0.465, 
     0.885}}],
  Polygon[{{-0.116, 0.472}, {0.116, 0.472}, {0., 1.}}]};
Graphics[{Red, p1, Blue, p2}]
RegionIntersection[p1, p2]
Area@%
RegionIntersection[Rationalize@p1, Rationalize@p2]
Area@%
```

[image]

> During evaluation of In[22]:= Part::partw: Part {2,3} of
>   {{0.116,0.472},{0.116,0.472}} does not exist. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[22]:= Set::partw: Part 3 of
>   {{0.116,0.472},{0.116,0.472}} does not exist. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[22]:= Part::partw: Part 3 of
>   {{0.116,0.472},{0.116,0.472}} does not exist. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[22]:= Set::partw: Part 3 of
>   {{0.116,0.472},{0.116,0.472}} does not exist. >>

```
(* RegionIntersection[
 Polygon[{{-0.116, 0.472}, {0.116, 0.472}, {0., 1.}}], 
 Polygon[{{0.322, 0.363}, {0.116, 0.472}, {0.465, 0.885}}]] *)
(* 0 *)
(* Point[{29/250, 59/125}] *)
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: What version are you using? While I also get the degenerate polygon from using `RegionIntersection` on the triangles, `Area@%` does give `0.`, using 10.4.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, well that is indeed odd.  I'm using [version 10.4 for linux](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1TMMu.png)

Comment: [I'm on Windows 10.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/f5nhL.png)

Comment: Linux always getting the shaft :-(

Comment: I've had similar-ish troubles with geometric stuff in 10.0.1. Inability to solve for line intersections etc. so I'd guess there might be a bug somewhere. I'll find an example and post soon.

Comment: The (undocumented!) function ``Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonIntersection[]`` returns `Polygon[{{}}]` (that is, an empty polygon) in all of the cases you gave, but this is of course no guarantee that this is any better than the kosher documented method.

Comment: @J.M. - but I have that hanging when the polygons actually do intersect.  Setting `{p1, p2} = {Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
   Polygon[{{0.5, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}}]};` and then running ``Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonIntersection[p1, p2]`` it just hangs

Comment: @JasonB sorry I post an answer without looking at your posted workaround.

Comment: Sadly regions functionality involving set operations, in especially tormenting ways with `Polygon`s and `MeshRegion`s is so buggy, that it's hard *not* to run into bugs with free-form input. Problems vary from odd representation and inability to compute values to incorrect results and outright repeatable kernel crashes. Practically every time I try to do polygon intersections or similar operations, I end up writing a new bug report and have to abandon my approach at problem using this functionality. I really wish these problems will eventually go away...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the examples given in the OP, this is fixed as of version 11.0

```
{p1, p2} = {Polygon[{{0., 0.354}, {-0.354, 0.}, {-0.707, 0.707}}], 
   Polygon[{{-0.707, -0.707}, {-0.354, 0.}, {-0.707, 0.707}}]};
Graphics[{Red, p1, Blue, p2}]
RegionIntersection[p1, p2]
Area@%
```

[image]

```
{p1, p2} = {Polygon[{{0.322, 0.363}, {0.116, 0.472}, {0.465, 0.885}}],
    Polygon[{{-0.116, 0.472}, {0.116, 0.472}, {0., 1.}}]};
Graphics[{Red, p1, Blue, p2}]
RegionIntersection[p1, p2]
Area@%
```

[image]